# Unespected result with type.GenericTypeArguments

Tags: c#, reflection

with reflection I'm getting list of a Method of a Controller, successfully.

to get the arguments of a returntype of a method I'm using *.GenericTypeArguments in this way:

```
Some MethodInfo x.GenericTypeArguments.Select(a => a.Name);
```

When method is like it:

```
public async Task<ApiResult> SomeMethod();
```

im getting the good result: "ApiResult"

But when the return tyle has a list like:

```
public async Task<List<string>> SomeMethod();
```

I'm getting -> Task,List,System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectArrayIterator`2[System.Type,System.String] instead of
Task,List,String

same for

```
public async Task<Dictionary<string,string>> SomeMethod();
```

expected Task,Dictionary,string,string

retrieved  Task,Dictionary,System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectArrayIterator`2[System.Type,System.String]

```
here the exact code I use:

            Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

            var controllerMethodlist = asm.GetTypes()
                    .Where(type => typeof(ControllerBase).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                    .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public))
                    .Where(m => !m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), true).Any())
                    .Select(x => new
                    {
                        Controller = x.DeclaringType.Name,
                        Action = x.Name + "(" + String.Join(",", x.GetParameters().Select(p => p.Name)) + ")",
                        ReturnType = x.ReturnType.Name.LastIndexOf('`') == -1 ? x.ReturnType.Name : (x.ReturnType.Name.Substring(0, x.ReturnType.Name.LastIndexOf('`')) + "<" +
                        String.Join(",", x.ReturnType.GenericTypeArguments.Select(a => a.Name.LastIndexOf('`') == -1 ? a.Name : a.Name.Substring(0, a.Name.LastIndexOf('`')) +
                        (a.GenericTypeArguments.Count() > 0 ? "<" + String.Join(",", a.GenericTypeArguments.Select(b => b.Name.LastIndexOf('`') == -1 ? b.Name : b.Name.Substring(0, b.Name.LastIndexOf('`')) +
                        (b.GenericTypeArguments.Count() > 0 ? "<" + String.Join(",", b.GenericTypeArguments.Select(c => c.Name.LastIndexOf('`') == -1 ? c.Name : c.Name.Substring(0, c.Name.LastIndexOf('`'))) + ">") : ""))) + ">" : ""))) + ">")
                        ,
                        Attributes = String.Join(",", x.GetCustomAttributes().Select(a => a.GetType().Name.Replace("Attribute", "") + "|" +
                        (
                            a.GetType() == typeof(HttpGetAttribute) ? ((HttpGetAttribute)a).Template :
                            a.GetType() == typeof(HttpPostAttribute) ? ((HttpPostAttribute)a).Template :
                            a.GetType() == typeof(HttpDeleteAttribute) ? ((HttpDeleteAttribute)a).Template :
                            a.GetType() == typeof(HttpPutAttribute) ? ((HttpPutAttribute)a).Template :
                            a.GetType() == typeof(CrudControllerAuthAttribute) ? ((CrudControllerAuthAttribute)a).CrudAuth.ToString() :
                            "*"
                        )))
                    })
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Controller).ThenBy(x => x.Action).ToList();
```

The problem is in "ReturnType" property:

I have following methods:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmEmail(parameters)
```

and as ResultType I'm getting correct value

```
Task<IActionResult>,
```

But with following method:

```
public async Task<ApiResultT<Dictionary<string,string>>> GetCsvDictionaryForTemplate(CsvBase64)
```

as ResultType I'm getting

```
`Task<ApiResultT<Dictionary<System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectArrayIterator`2[System.Type,System.String]>>>`
```

instead of

```
Task<ApiResultT<Dictionary<string,string>>>
```

or with following method:

```
public async Task<ApiResultT<List<CsvClassesDto>>> GetCsvClasses()
```

I'm getting:

```
Task<ApiResultT<List<System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectArrayIterator`2[System.Type,System.String]>>>
```

Instead of:

```
Task<ApiResultT<List<CsvClassesDto>>>
```

So the problem i have when the Type is a List or a dictionary so an Enumerable.

I hope to heva been clear

Thankyou for help

Piercarlo

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. There is no property called `GenericTypeArguments` in the class `MethodInfo`.

Comment: Can you post your actual code instead of this: `Some MethodInfo x.GenericTypeArguments.Select(a => a.Name);`. It's not clear how you're reading the Generic Type arguments of the *nested* (not meant literally) Generic Types that define the return Type of those methods. -- Since you have to read all arguments of each Type while `IsGenericType = true`, maybe there's something wrong in the procedure.